# How to show tables rows into cols in mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, api, join, pivot

I have wordpress table and have to use in api so i am using wpkt_postmeta and wpkt_post tables.

and i need to show _sku,_regular_price,_sale_price,_price,_stock as column name and put their values into respective col.

My query is

```
SELECT wpkt_posts.id,
       wpkt_posts.post_name,
       wpkt_postmeta.meta_key,
       wpkt_postmeta.meta_value
FROM   wpkt_posts
       JOIN wpkt_postmeta
         ON wpkt_posts.id = wpkt_postmeta.post_id
WHERE  wpkt_posts.id = 280
       AND wpkt_postmeta.meta_key IN ( '_sku', '_regular_price', '_sale_price',
                                       '_price',
                                       '_stock' )
```

[image]
This is actual result

[image]
But i want in this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider handling this in your application code. However, you can use conditional aggregation with `Group By`:

```
SELECT wpkt_posts.id,
       wpkt_posts.post_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_key = '_sku' 
                THEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_value END) AS _sku, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                THEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_value END) AS _regular_price,     
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_key = '_price' 
                THEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_value END) AS _price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_key = '_sale_price' 
                THEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_value END) AS _sale_price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock' 
                THEN wpkt_postmeta.meta_value END) AS _stock
FROM wpkt_posts
JOIN wpkt_postmeta ON wpkt_posts.id = wpkt_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wpkt_posts.id = 280 
  AND wpkt_postmeta.meta_key IN ( '_sku', 
                                  '_regular_price', 
                                  '_sale_price',
                                  '_price',
                                  '_stock' ) 
GROUP BY wpkt_posts.id, 
         wpkt_posts.post_name
```